# How can I find the boundaries of a subset of a sorted list?

Tags: algorithm, search

I have the following dilemma: I have a list of strings, and I want to find the set of string which start with a certain prefix. The list is sorted, so the naive solution is this:

Perform binary search on the prefixes of the set, and when you find an element that starts with the prefix, traverse up linearly until you hit the top of the subset.

This runs in linear time, however, and I was wondering if anyone can suggest a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Just do a binary search for the top as well.

Comment: what characters are in your string?  wondering if you can do binary searches for <prefix>0 and <prefix>Z to get your bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a binary search for the top, and do a binary search for the bottom.  Once you find the first hit, you know the top is above that point and the bottom is below (or at that point in both cases).  Once you have the top and bottom you have the solution.

Comment: You dont know what they are, but thats why you are doing the search.  You start the search at the top and bottom of the entire list, then you split it in half.  A typical binary search would only have one result, the first or last element.  In your search when you hit the first element, you need to then execute a binary search from that point using the lower half to find the last element you need and the upper half to find the first element.  This will prevent 2 binary searches on the whole thing as finding the first element could take some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a similar binary search for the top element, except that the string you should be looking for is the first string that starts with a prefix strictly greater than the prefix in question.  This also takes O(lg n) time.

Comment: I disagree... you just told him the quickest way to find the first element and the slowest way to find the last.  Once you find the first only half the work is done... you need to find the last... which may be 2 away or may be 500k away.  3 binary searches are needed to complete this.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  The same technique you can use to find the first element in the sequence with the prefix can easily be adapted to find the last using a binary search.  With two binary searches (time O(lg n)) you can find the bounds on the range.  The naive linear search takes time O(lg n + k), since you do one binary search plus a linear search.  Also, I don't know what you mean by "the slowest way to find the last"; a naive linear search takes time O(n) to find the last element, and my O(lg n) search is exponentially faster.

Answer (score 0):

Once you find one element in the set, just keep binary searching until you find the endpoints.